# Which less-variable changes/remove the color/fading animation for links/menus in Ant Design?

Tags: less, antd, ant-design-pro

I have included the less files for Ant Design (antd) into my React-app, because I want to customise the theme, as explained [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) and [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less). However, I am uncertain which variables to change, to edit or remove the fading-effect when hovering menu-items. (I.e. I would like the text and background color of the hovered menu item to change faster or immediately.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve that level of customization through editing theme variable. you would need to manually apply custom css on those elements that you would like to  customize, eg

for example, making the hover animation to 4s while you hover it.

```
.ant-menu-item:hover {
  transition-duration: 4s;
}
```

to find exact classname you can always inspect the node

using the same idea you can fit your custom needs.